# Spring Boot HttpSecurity upgrading

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I get the error

```
"message": "Failed to evaluate expression '(hasRole('SYS_PERM_DATASET') or hasRole('SYS_PERM_DESKTOP_MANAGE')) and @tenantChecker.verify()'"
```

I'm trying to update some legacy spring boot stuff to Spring Boot 3/Security 6.1. I have the code:

```java
.authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                    .requestMatchers("/config/migrate", "/config/downloadallconfig", "/processes/secure/**")
                        .access(new WebExpressionAuthorizationManager("hasRole('ROLE_SYS_PERM_PMGT_USER') and @tenantChecker.verify()"))
                    .requestMatchers("/processes/**", "/event/**", "/jsonevent/**")
                        .permitAll()
                )
```

Is this an issue around how I am calling the string in WebExpressionAuthorizationManager or could it be an issue with the individual methods hasRole or tenantChecker.verify?